Telegram и эмулятор андроид
На компьютере с ОС Windows 11, установлен Android-эмулятор MEmu.
В нём установлено приложение Telegram. Оно работает исправно.
Интересует следующий вопрос: Что видит интернет-провайдер когда пользуешься Telegram на эмуляторе Android?
У них отсвечивается, что идёт использование Telegram? Что именно отображаеться?

Интернет провайдер ничего видеть не может, ведь внутрь трафика не влезет. Да и плевать ему на факт эмулятора. А вот знают ли сервера телеги что это эмуль? Это да, ведь детектить эмулятор довольно просто.
